# How to get rid of Cannot focus element exception

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I faced with following issue with `chromedriver`: I have a text input field and a texarea. I can successfully send text to both elements with follow code

```
input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="text"]')
input.send_keys('test')
textarea = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//textarea[not(@readonly)]')
textarea.send_keys('test')
```

But if to try this code

```
text_fields = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[input[@type="text"] or textarea[not(@readonly)]]')
for field in text_fields:
    field.send_keys('test')
```

I get `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element`

P.S. Adding `field.click()` before sending text or using `ActionChains` failed to solve issue. Also `len(text_fields)` return `2`, so both elements correctly matched with `XPath`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second expression will return the parent element of the `input` or `textarea`. If you wish to get both in a single XPath then:

```
text_fields = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@type='text'] | //textarea[not(@readonly)]")
for field in text_fields:
    field.send_keys('test')
```

Or with a CSS selector :

```
text_fields = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("input[type='text'] , textarea:not([readonly])")
for field in text_fields:
    field.send_keys('test')
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot